# Closing of mosques during epidemics and plagues

Tags: history, masjid

As we know, during the times of Umar RA, there was a plague. It was believed at that time as it is believed now also that if one is infected, the disease may spread to closed ones. This can be known by the following hadith:

> A bedouin asked, “O Allah’s Messenger! What about the camels which,
> when on the sand [desert] look like deers, but when a camel. with an
> itch mixes with them, they are all infected with itchiness?”. On that,
> the Holy Prophetsa said, “Then who conveyed the disease [itch] to the
> first camel?” (Sahih al-Bukhari, Book of Medicine)

So my questions are related to behaviors adopted during this very plague:

1. were mosques closed?
2. were congregation prayers or even gatherings banned?
3. was social distancing being practiced in mosques?
4. Were families of infected people banned from entering mosques or congregational prayers?
5. Were those who took care of infected people banned from entering mosques or congregation prayers?
6. Before Covid-19, has it ever happened that mosques were closed because of epidemics in the times of Nabi SAW, or four caliphs of Islam, or even after?

Comment: Nothing of the sort was done.

Comment: 6. Depends on what you mean by even after.

Comment: The first who practiced social distancing one could say was 'Amr ibn al-'Aas during the plague of 'Amwaas when he ordered his army to disperse in the mountains. This way he could save them from the plague and the caliph 'Umar () didn't disapprove his doing.

Answer (score -4):

The answer to questions 1-5 is : NO and NEVER

Comment: Please provide evidences!